# Fetching Json Array with a single element android studio

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I am having a json array which has a single element in my json array response. How do i fetch it using volley JsonArrayRequest or String request

Below is my response from a link

```
[
    2020
]
```

Below is what i have tried but am still getting a 0 from the response instead of 2020

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfdpnEfDhe?indent=2",
                response -> {

                    if (response.length() == 0) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Response is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {

                        try {

                            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                                    .setMessage(String.valueOf(response.getDouble(0)))
                                    .show();

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }

                }, error -> {

            error.printStackTrace();


        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put("username", "username");
                headers.put("password", "123456789");

                Log.d("HeadersAuthFailureError", "HeadersAuthFailureError: " + super.getHeaders());

                return headers;

            }

            
        };


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireActivity());
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your response is indexed value, should use [JSONArrayRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray)